# Magento 2.3.2: server status 200 with page not found

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, vue-storefront

How can I set server status 404 with vue component page_not_found? Now server status 404 only with dinamic catalog undefined pages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide URL where I can help you?